# mongoose sub-documents not created with unique id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating an application based on quizzes. Each quiz consists of certain attributes and rounds. Each round, likewise, consists of certain attributes and questions. Each question also consists of a number of attributes.

I originally created a database scheme which involved multiple collections (quizzes, rounds and questions) with fields which related it to its respective parent e.g. each round would have stored its relevant quiz' ID.

However, I came across mongoose' concept of sub-documents (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) and thought this would give my items a better relationship. So after re-architecting my app, I have found that sub docs on the tertiary level (questions) are not generating their own unique IDs - the ID is that of their parent (round).

Screenshot below of resulting database.[image: Resulting database]

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Can mongoose sub documents be utilised for this amount of levels? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Scheme code:

```
/* Questions */

var questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    displayOrder: { type: Number, default: 0 }, 
    questionText: { type: String, default: 'Question' }, 
    answer: { type: String, default: 'Answer' }, 
    points: { type: Number, default: 1 }, 
    timeInSeconds: { type: Number, default: 10 }
});

var Question = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
exports.Question = Question;

/* Rounds */

var roundSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, default: 'New round' }, 
    displayOrder: { type: Number, default: 0 }, 
    questions: [questionSchema]
});

var Round = mongoose.model('Round', roundSchema);
exports.Round = Round;

/* Quizzes */

var quizSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, default: 'New quiz' }, 
    rounds: [roundSchema]
});

var Quiz = mongoose.model('Quiz', quizSchema);
exports.Quiz = Quiz;
```

Resftul API code (parts of):

```
exports.addQuiz = function(req, res) {
    var quiz = new db.Quiz({
        title: 'Quiz'
    });
quiz.save();    
    return res.redirect('/admin/quiz/edit/' + quiz._id);
};

exports.addRound = function(req, res, next) {
    db.Quiz.findOne({ _id: req.params.quizId }, function(err, foundQuiz) {
    var round = foundQuiz.rounds.create();
        foundQuiz.rounds.push(round);
        foundQuiz.save(function(err) {
            return res.json(round);         
        });
    });
};

exports.addQuestion = function(req, res, next) {
    db.Quiz.findOne({ _id: req.params.quizId }, function(err, foundQuiz) {
        var round = foundQuiz.rounds.id(req.params.roundId),
        question = round.questions.create();
        round.questions.push(round);
        foundQuiz.save(function(err) {
            return res.json(question);          
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what am I missing here? Which sub-document is not generating a unique `_id`? They all seem to be there in your screenshot. It is also a "mongoose" convention and is **not** a requirement of MongoDB. But they are **always** there by default on arrays.

Comment: If you look at the _id assigned to the round and question documents, they are identical.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?